# How is the screen space allocated in Android's layout_weight attribute?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am using 4 textviews in a linear layout. I have assigned a weight of 3 to one textview and a weight of 1 to the remaining three textviews. I want to know how the screen real estate is calculated and allocated to each textview based on the assigned weight.

Comment: The sum of all weights is the total, and the individual weights are the fraction of that total, pretty straight forward really.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does android:layout\_weight mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean)

Comment: I agree, but what happens when one of the views is assigned a weight of 0 but is still present on the screen? How does that fraction work out?

Comment: Layout_weight distributes _extra_ space among views, you cannot use it to hide a view. It's all in the link.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the linear layout with

```
 android:weightSum="1"
```

and then this 1 represents 100% of the height/width (whatever you are using)

then in your textview if you use

```
android:layout_weight="0.2"
```

then you're giving the textview 20% of the layout space, and so on.